# Should I create an object of a class or static method to check if a db entry exists?

Tags: oop

I'm new to OOP design concepts and was wondering what the correct approach is for the following use case (I'm developing with JavaScript and Mongo but I think the question is a general one):

I have `User` as a collection/table and have wrapped the interaction with this user with a class. My idea is to abstract away the DB interaction from the main program. 
There are cases where I need to check if a `user` already exists in the DB:

If it does: use the information of this user.
If it doesn't: cary on with the flow and redirect the user to some page

- Option 1: Does it make sense to create an instance of the User class just to check if it exists?
- Option 2: having something like a static method in the class to do this job, but also doesn't seem right since if the user exist I want to use it's info and I would need to create it again.

Option 1:

```
let user = new User(name);

if (user.isExist()){
   //do something with user properties
} else {
   //redirect to /someRoute
}
```

Option 2:

```
if (User.isExist(name)){
  let user = new User(name);
  //do something with user properties
} else {
   //redirect to /someRoute
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Feedback to Option-1 and Option-2

This solution would break the *[Single-Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)* and the *[Open-Closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle)* principle.

When you would model your class you have to think of logic for the `User` and how to handle persistence-transactions. The persistence-transactions need to be changed when you switch for example from Mongo to SQL..

So lets split the logic into separate classes.

## Add a new Class!

I could think of a class `UserTransaction` which handles the persistence-transactions.

```
class UserTransaction {
    constructor(/*...*/) {/*...*/}

    static existsWithTheName(name) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Than your code would look like:

```
if (UserTransaction.existsWithTheName(name)){
  let user = new User(name);
} else {
   //redirect to /someRoute
}
```